# How would I issue two Facebook request in the same class? iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all photos from the different albums of a user. So I write a request `me/albums` then in `didLoad` I get an array of albums, which I can use the id of each album to issue a new request `albumId/photos` but how should I do that? Should I add the request in the `didLoad`, but then, how would I know them apart?

Answer (score 3):

Ok this is how I do it might not be the best way to go about it but it works. In the did load

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

NSString *requestType =[request.url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"request %@",requestType); }
```

Now the requestType would be either me/albums or albumId/photos. Put in a couple a conditional if-statements and you are good to go. And yes you can add the new request for fetching photos from the albums in the didLoad in the if condition that matches me/albums (meaning you got some result for that request ie the albums array). The next time you hit the didLoad it would be for the photos in the albums. Hope that helps.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it appears to be the only approach since the only possible way to determine the nature of the result is to inspect the request. Although i'd be very interested to find out a better approach to this too. :)

Comment: If the delegate method would have taken a block it would be pretty:)

Answer (score 3):

you could also keep the refs to the `FBRequest` instance returned by each `requestWithGraphPath` call and match them with the ref. you get when the delegate methods are called back.